# Selected Dates ACF Multi Dates Field not displaying in WP Fullcalendar

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar, fullcalendar, advanced-custom-fields

I have installed the Plugin Advanced Custom Fields https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ and the ACF Multi Dates Field https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-multi-dates-picker/ so I can be able to pick different dates but after having selected the dates, I realize that they are not reflected in the WP Fullcalendar calendar. I am not very good with the part of the code so I need someone to help me to know what part of the php code I should modify from the WP Fullcalendar plugin so that the dates are reflected.

The link of the calendar: https://unihosanna.online/calendario-de-cursos-en-vivo/

Comment: I was going to suggest you post a question on the wp full calendar support forum but I see you already have :)
My inital guess is that fullcalendar uses the post publish date field to display posts and, for this to work, it would need to recognize that date custom field to display posts.
It's not immediately apparent to me if that's an option.

Comment: When I use only one date it recognizes it but in this case I want to put multiple dates in one post, the calendar does not recognize them. This is why I think it is a part of the code that needs to be modified from WP Fullcalendar